# SQL Server : insert into another table values if requirement met in other table

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @AccountID VARCHAR(10)

SELECT @AccountID = AccountID
FROM MuOnlineSlow.dbo.T_VIPList 
WHERE Type = 1

INSERT INTO MUONLINEWEBS.dbo.MUONLINEWEBS_WEB_WAREHOUSE ([AccountID], [name_full], [name], [history], [hex], [cat], [itemid], [level], [luck], [skill], [excellent], [ancient], [time], [has_exe_1], [has_exe_2], [has_exe_4], [has_exe_8], [has_exe_16], [has_exe_32], [socket_exe_6], [socket_exe_7], [socket_exe_8], [server])
VALUES (@AccountID, 
        '<span style="color:;font-family: tahoma;font-size: 12px;">Bundle of Jewel of Soul </span>', 
        'Bundle of Jewel of Soul', 
        'VIP REWARD',
         '1F0000000000000000C000FFFFFFFFFF0001D560FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF',
         12, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         1542466494, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'DEFAULT')
```

Problem is that query inserts only last information found in `T_VIPList` table into `WEB_WAREHOUSE` table, but I have 6 rows with different `AccountID`. Why doesn't it enter the new information in the `WEB_WAREHOUSE` with all `AccountID`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something closer to this, which will SELECT all of the AccountIDs from your VIPList with Type 1:

```
INSERT INTO MUONLINEWEBS.dbo.MUONLINEWEBS_WEB_WAREHOUSE 
    ([AccountID], ..., [server]))
    SELECT vip.AccountID, ..., 'DEFAULT'
         FROM MuOnlineSlow.dbo.T_VIPList vip
         WHERE vip.Type = 1;
```

And, *assuming* AccountID is your primary key, you could make the insert safer by checking for existence:

```
INSERT INTO MUONLINEWEBS.dbo.MUONLINEWEBS_WEB_WAREHOUSE 
    ([AccountID], ..., [server]))
    SELECT vip.AccountID, ..., 'DEFAULT'
         FROM MuOnlineSlow.dbo.T_VIPList vip
         WHERE vip.Type = 1
             AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                                FROM MUONLINEWEBS.dbo.MUONLINEWEBS_WEB_WAREHOUSE w
                                WHERE w.AccountID = vip.AccountID);
```

Comment: Well my idea is to insert manually typed Values with replaced AccountID from T_VIPList table. Everything works, but like i said, it inserts only last rows AccountID.

Comment: @wiraly The fundamental problem with your approach is that `@AccountID` is a variable that can only hold a single value. You need to use a `SELECT` statement to get all of the different AccountIDs in a single `INSERT`.

Comment: Good Job. Thank you for your answer. This worker like i wanted - 
INSERT INTO MUONLINEWEBS.dbo.MUONLINEWEBS_WEB_WAREHOUSE 
    ([AccountID], ..., [server]))
    SELECT vip.AccountID, ..., 'DEFAULT'
         FROM MuOnlineSlow.dbo.T_VIPList vip
         WHERE vip.Type = 1;

Answer (score 0):

@AccountID is a variable that can only hold one value, not a list/array/vector. So if you wonder why your SELECT doesn't throw an error when the FROM with WHERE returns 6 rows and therefore 6 values are to be assigned to a variable: because this is one of the nondeterministic behaviours of SQL. A random value "wins" and will be assigned from the 6 returned.  So you need to combine INSERT with SELECT without variables to get all rows (= a table) as other answer(s) show(s).